# Emails send from server with cPanel using php go to outlook.com junk/spam folder

Tags: php, email, smtp, cpanel, outlook.com

When I send an email from e.g. a php (phpmailer) script or SquirrelMail from my cPanel server to outlook.com the emails end up in the junk/spam folder. Sending an email from the same script or email address to another provider e.g. gmail.com will deliver the email into the inbox where it should be.

I've setup and tested for it to be valid:

- dkim
- spf
- dmark
- reverse dns

The server (IP), domain are not blacklisted.
The email that is send passes spamassasin without any problems.

The emails send via phpmailer are send using the SMTP setup that comes with cPanel.

Would love to hear your thoughts on this one.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to test your mailer. Go to https://www.mail-tester.com/ and use their tool to test everything is configured correctly.

If everything appears ok using the tool, it may be worth whitelisting your server with multiple ISPs.

You should be able to find information on how to do this using Google, but here is some links to get you started.

**Hotmail/Outlook:**
http://mail.live.com/mail/services.aspx

**Yahoo**: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/bulkv2.html

Comment: I've tried https://www.mail-tester.com/ and I got a perfect score there.

I'll have a look at 'whitelisting your server with multiple ISP', thanks for the heads up on this. Though I find it awkward that this happens with a new server, new domain and fresh ip address (maybe this is the problem?!).

Comment: An alternative is to send your mail via an established mail server such as:

https://sendgrid.com/ who allow 12,000 a month for free or http://mandrill.com/

Comment: I also have a 10/10 in mail-tester.com but still all my email goes to Junk Folder when sent to any outlook.com account.

Comment: Ya, this issue normally happened for new IP/Domain, it will take a while to warm up your IP, maybe you can use your domain send something simple, small, no HTML, just text only, and try to tell google or other mail providers that are not spam.